# How do I get the 96x96 DPI Size of the current form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, resize, dpi

I am modifying a piece of existing code for my company. We currently have our own custom form which stores its size in the configuration files so that, when the user returns, the window is the same size as it was before. The catch I'm noticing is that, after testing with higher DPI settings, the size being stored is the inflated one from the minimum size necessary at that DPI setting. To give an example, I have a login form which is 374 x 243 at 96x96 DPI. When I load the application at 150%, the form expands to 695x467, a little less than double the dimensions in either direction. If I change my computer back to 100% on the DPI, the login form stays at 695x467, a much larger display at that DPI.

The code we are using to store the size is as follows:

```
        AppConfig.GetAppConfig().SetFormAttrValue(Name, "LocationX", Location.X);
        AppConfig.GetAppConfig().SetFormAttrValue(Name, "LocationY", Location.Y);

        AppConfig.GetAppConfig().SetFormAttrValue(Name, "Width", Size.Width);
        AppConfig.GetAppConfig().SetFormAttrValue(Name, "Height", Size.Height);
```

Is there a good property to read to get the non-scaled size of the form? My suspicion, based on the non-linear increase in size from 100% to 150% turning into more of 185% increase, is that this is going to be a tougher nut to crack than I'd like (I'd initially hoped to be able to do transformations based on the `Graphics.DpiX` and `Graphics.DpiY` objects), but I figured I would ask in case someone knew of an easy answer. Thank you.

Comment: i'm sure someone has an answer for you, but honestly, the way you are storing the form's size, is just that, the form's size... if you're messing with the DPI/Zoom on your desktop, the form's size doesn't change at all, and that's normal. It should remain with set sized parameters, not Size VS Zoom parameters... in my mind anyway.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv: That would be ideal, but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work that way. The Size values are noticeably different, although I think that might have to do the fact that the form is set to AutoSize as necessary to fit the controls in it. Grow the controls for the new DPI setting and it grows the form.

Comment: have you tried to debug that? e.g.: put a button on the form for testing, and in the button click event, fire off a messagebox that tells you what the form's size actually is. Change the DPI, alert size, now you know what the system sees for size on each DPI setting... ;) -- The AutoSize might be a good check/place to start looking if the size does change on DPI change.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv: Yup. That's how I got the figures above. That's also the increased size that's being stored. For the form I'm testing on, a log-in screen, we may be able to fix it by simply disabling saving resizes, but it shows up on our other forms too.

Comment: Ok... let me research this a little and I will post a solution for you. I'm sure that some calculation can be used to determine the proper size... probably by tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only answer i have for you is a bit of a workaround... if it were me, i would simply store the form's size, with a DPI header in order to get the right one...

to get the DPI from the screen in C#:

```
using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    float dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
    float dpiY = graphics.DpiY;
}
```

with this information, you could save in your config file the size of the form based on the DPI... then load the proper size based on the reading of the DPI above. The name of your config value could be something like "Size_At_96_96", and then the value would be the form's size...

Sorry if i don't have any more answers for you, but what i found is that unless you work with WPF, what you are experiencing happens to everybody.